# C# Programming Assignment

Tags: c#

The teacher wants me to create 2 files & insert random characters inside. Both files should be the same length. In one file a keyword "Hello" should be inserted randomly.

I did this for the first file:

```
var stringChars = new char[100];
var random = new Random();
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];

}
```

I did this for the second file:

```
   var stringChars2 = new char[100];
   var random2 = new Random();
   var chars2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZxxxxx";

   for (int i = 0; i < stringChars2.Length; i++)
   {
       stringChars2[i] = chars2[random2.Next(chars2.Length)];

   }


   string string2 = new string(stringChars2);
   string2 = string2.Replace("x", "\"Hello\"");
```

My problem is I don't know how to make the length of both files equal with the string replace trick. The second file will always be longer.

Comment: There are other ways to replace a substring than by replacing a pre-existing pattern. For example, replacing a particular range of characters by location.

Comment: Your basic logic is flawed. All `var chars2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZxxxxx";` is doing is **increasing** the changes of there being a lowercase "x" in the file. Then, when you call `Replace`, you're going to be inserting one instance of the string "Hello" for *each* of those lowercase xs. And if you don't have any lowercase xs, you won't get *any* "Hello"s.

Comment: @mrjoltcola That was a good hint without giving an answer

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback! @mrjoltcola so like when the random string is called I can replace 5 characters in a specific location with the keyword? That is the idea right?

Comment: In first file, Just insert 5 x characters extra as many occurrances of 'Hello' you put in second file, and get rid of the 5 x's. Also, write some tests!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I see. I'm sorry about that,being a nurse those words are like second nature to me. I want to be a programmer and I can see from some posts that the attitude is different. I will keep it in mind :D

Comment: @Airynd Personally, I always say please & thank you.

Comment: @Airynd - Don't misunderstand, it isn't "programmers" that have the different attitude, it is Stack Overflow and the site policy. The goal is to build high quality material, and not provide a chat forum, but it frankly encourages a "borg"-like hive-mind coldness that I don't care for. You say thanks all you want. If moderators want to clean it up, let them.

Comment: @mrjoltcola: if you don't like the policy, then the place to discuss it is [meta]. It's not helpful for you to encourage users to violate the policy. Violate it yourself if you want to, and the community (I'm not a moderator) will clean it up as necessary.

Comment: I never said I didn't like the policy, I said I didn't care for the coldness that it encourages - there is a difference if you read my comment. And I was frankly defending the site policy to a new user who isn't on Meta.

Comment: @mrjoltcola thank you for making the clarification :D

Comment: PS: I don't know whether this is legally within policy or not, but I personally will say thanks or welcome in a comment, and then delete the comment shortly afterwards (ie. "this message will self destruct in 3 seconds"). Deleting the comment allows me to be compliant with policy, but should deliver the message to the recipient (inbox at top left of screen). I actually will ask about that on Meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an object oriented approach.  I emphasize this approach since you have to perform similar operations multiple times (two).  Thus, you shouldn't repeat yourself (google DRY prinicpal).

I won't tell you how to use these methods, you can figure that our for yourself:

```
public static class StringManipulation
{
    public static string GetXRandomCharacters(int x)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var random = new Random();
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(chars[random.Next(chars.Length)]);
        }

        return sb;
    }

    public static string InjectWordAtRandom(string str, string word)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        int start = random.Next(str.Length - word.Length);

        str.Remove(start, word.Length).Insert(start, word);
    }
}
```

**Hint:**  I have provided static methods but you don't have to do it that way.  Try removing `static` from the method headers and creating an instance of the class to access it's properties.